# Sou obrigado a ser formal nas perguntas/respostas?

Tags: debate

Seguinte, vejam essa [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/31350/revisions) foi escrito o seguinte nas respostas:

> Rsrs, realmente, são coisas que passam desapercebidas....

e

> So isso...

São formas de falar características de "amigos", que criam certo vinculo, querendo ou não porque estamos sendo informais... sei lá, acho que isso não afeta no entendimento da resposta, claro que temos que ser objetivos, mas enfim.... sempre tive esse modo informal de escrever em todos fóruns, ou em todos ambientes online que participei.... devo/devemos ser sempre formal/is no SO?

Comment: Eu costumo deixar esse tipo de conteúdo nos comentários assim ninguém se chateia muito ;)

Comment: Aparentemente a comunidade aprova a remoção de ruídos das publicações, mais detalhes pode ver nesse tópico: [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3117)

Comment: Nas perguntas geralmente eu dou uma "formalizada", mas em resposta eu acho que foi um pouco de exagero. Gostei do resultado final, mas acho que resposta pode ser mais pessoal.

Comment: Acho que o `Rsss` não é adequado, pois é linguagem de Twitter, Chat e semelhantes. ++10 pro que diz @JorgeB.

Comment: Eu sou mais informal em comentários. Nas respostas, acho que o interessante é ser mais objetivo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não é necessário ser sempre formal. Nem é tão comum edições que simplesmente alterem esse tipo de coisa.

Porém, o excesso de "palavras amigáveis" é também ruído e muitas vezes não agrega em nada para os visitantes do site. Um "Bom dia" ou "Boa tarde", por exemplo, pode parecer simpático, mas sem sentido para todo o resto do mundo.

A experiência dos usuários numa comunidade como o SO se divide...

Por um lado você está se comunicando diretamente com o autor da pergunta e, nesse caso, não faz mal algum algumas palavras a mais.

Por outro lado, milhares de outras pessoas vão ver essa questão. Para elas, os cumprimentos e comentários não essenciais são irrelevantes e até atrapalham.

Especificamente quanto à edição da sua pergunta, ela não era 100% necessário, mas com certeza ajudou a deixar a resposta um pouco mais clara.

A comunidade do SOpt (StackOverflow em Português) é certamente uma comunidade aberta e amigável, porém os usuários prezam bastante pela qualidade do conteúdo.

Minha sugestão é tentar encontrar um equilíbrio entre ser cordial, formal e direto. Nunca seja excessivamente cordial, evite ser excessivamente formal e cuidado em ser excessivamente direto, sem explicar como sua solução funciona.

Comment: Sem contar que a utilização de um português formal pode auxiliar pessoas que não falem português à traduzir a questão que possa auxiliá-las.
Não faz sentido utilizar gírias, ou "internetês"/ emojis e afins pois pode dificultar a leitura por estrangeiros.