# Devemos aceitar piadinhas em comentários?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comentários

Eu já pensei em perguntar isso antes, mas como isso nunca foi um problema muito grande, acabei deixando pra lá.

Mas hoje um usuário ficou chateado com piadinhas na pergunta: [O que é código spaghetti?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/7261) (alguns dos comentários já foram apagados).

Teoricamente, comentários deveriam ser apenas para acrescentar informação útil, chamar atenção para algo, etc. Porém é comum que de vez em quando apareça alguma piadinha, tanto no site principal como aqui no Meta. Acontece no Stack-EN também.

Será que está na hora de ser um pouco mais rígido com isto?

Comment: Eu sou contra vetar qualquer tipo de comentário bem-humorado. Não precisamos ser tão sérios. O problema é esses comentários tomarem conta e desviarem o foco da pergunta. Nesses casos, precisam ser sinalizados para que os moderadores façam uma limpeza (isso se os próprios autores não excluírem os comentários antes).

Comment: Poderiam incluir uma tag do tipo 'humor' pra quando o usuário fizer um comentário humorado...

Comment: Relacionado: [Uso de emoticons e smileys em comentários](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1299/3117)

Comment: Morte às Piadinhas! Pra vereador, vote Negativo!

Comment: O problema é que na escrita a entonação de um tom mais humorado não existe, ou é difícil passar. Eu me policio ao máximo para não me fazer entender equivocadamente e quando a situação obriga uso um singelo `:)` para mostrar que estou escrevendo com a melhor das intenções.

Answer (score 21):

Minha visão sobre a coisa é esta:

### Cada um sabe o que deve aceitar ou não.

Motivo: comentários são **apenas comentários** e são de natureza pessoal de quem comenta. O espaço dos comentários já está aí pra isso, e já existem as ferramentas para se tratar do problema individualmente. Se comentaram algo inconveniente na **sua** postagem ou fizeram uma menção que ofendeu **você ou um grupo com quem você se identifica**, sinalize.

Se no SOpt quase tudo é orientação e bom senso, e quase nada regra, o lugar mais inadequado para se querer um comportamento padronizado é nos comentários.

O SOzão tem piadas geniais que muitas vezes não contribuem com nada e são inclusive bem votadas. Aqui já tivemos alguns casos, mas acho que falta humor no SOpt para melhorar <sup>1</sup>.

**Em resumo:**

A pergunta é relevante. A resposta/solução já está embutida no mecanismo do site, que em resumo é: Quem se incomodou que tome a providência cabível, pois as ferramentas estão aí.

<sub>1. Inclusive, na minha humilde opinião e experiência de vida, tenho percebido que o bom humor está associado à capacidade de abstração e raciocínio, e o mau humor exatamente o inverso, mas aí já estamos partindo para outra seara...</sub>

Answer (score 11):

Bom humor é, via de regra, aceito no Stack Overflow quando pertinente à discussão.

Um dos maiores exemplos que posso citar é [a resposta mais famosa do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2263584).

No entanto, concordo com os demais: a zoeira tem limites, e se os comentários começarem a ficar off-topic, não vejo problemas em apagá-los.

*Mea culpa* agora: fui eu quem começou a palha-assada, embora não tivesse sido essa minha intenção. Soltei esta pérola:

> @MarceloBonifazio eu fiquei surpreso, pois trabalho com programação há uns 10 anos e nunca tinha ouvido falar de código lasanha e código ravioli (sério, olha lá!). Vou ver se encontro algo sobre código fusilli pois é minha massa favorita XD

Acontece que fiz isso pra chamar atenção ao fato de que, além do *código macarrão*, existem também o *código lasanha* e o *código ravioli*. Até onde vi, são todos **termos técnicos reais** e isso me surpreendeu. Concordo que o que postei depois sobre código fusilli foi gratuito e desnecessário e adoraria mudar isso, porém o período no qual posso editar o comentário já passou.

Prometo ser menos gastronômico daqui pra frente.

Comment: Pelo menos não foi uma piada de **mau gosto**. Na verdade até achei que *foi **massa***.

Answer (score 6):

É permitido postar piadinhas nos comentários, entretanto tudo tem um limite. Geralmente as piadinhas que são aceitas pela comunidade acrescentam algo de útil na postagem, ou seja, são comentários informativos que entretanto puxam um pouco para o lado do humor.

Em outras palavras, a regra para dizer se aceitamos um comentário ou não, não é com base em se ele é engraçado ou chato, é em se ele é construtivo ou não (ou alguma das outras opções como ofensivo e etc), e você pode ser construtivo sem deixar o humor de lado.

Veja a janela de sinalização de comentários e preste atenção no segundo motivo de fechamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Obs: os motivos de sinalização estão usando os comentários como se fossem substantivos femininos, e deveria ser corrigido.</sup>

Entretanto os comentários na sua pergunta não eram construtivos, e assim como bem instruiu o @bfavarretto nos comentários, eu havia sinalizado alguns deles, eles foram excluídos e as sinalizações marcadas como úteis.

Sobre o fato do usuário que ficou chateado, não tenho certeza, mas acho que ele tinha entendido que sua pergunta era uma *trollagem* e por isso tentou fechá-la, por causa do título da pergunta que poderia parecer estranho para alguns usuários e pelo excesso de comentários off-topic que falavam sobre pizza, planalto e etc.

Comment: Você me compreendeu. No entanto não é uma questão de ficar chateado. O que me levou a votar para fechar a pergunta foi que, após ler o comentário do OP, fiquei com a sensação que o intuito da pergunta era provocar esse tipo de comentários. Além do mais, e peço desculpa se estiver enganado, não achei verdadeira a frase do OP: *"Porém nunca consegui entender com clareza o que "código spaghetti" significa."* No final disto tudo, tendo razão ou não, estou contente pela discussão gerada, pois penso que será útil para mudar a forma como alguns se relacionam com o site.

Comment: @ramaral de fato "chateado" não é a palavra mais adequada, mas eu acabei por usá-la pois foi assim que o AP escreveu, e eu não me atentei para encontrar uma palavra que representasse melhor a situação.

Answer (score 5):

Até parece que Andrey e Marcelo combinaram:

<kbd>[image: Devemos aceitar piadinhas em comentários? vs Sou obrigado a ser formal nas P&R?]</kbd>

Respostas: **sim** (com direito a ser deletado) e **não** (mas podendo ser editado).

Acho que o [comentário do Jorge B.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1920/sou-obrigado-a-ser-formal-nas-perguntas-respostas#comment5848_1920) a respeito da formalidade responde bem aqui:

> [image: Eu costumo deixar esse tipo de conteúdo nos comentários assim ninguém se chateia muito ;)]