# Como são vistas piadinhas em comentários e até em perguntas ou respostas?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Como uma comunidade é feita de pessoas, um usuário de humor mais aguçado, digamos assim, pode às vezes soltar um texto com alguma piadinha, seja nos comentários, na pergunta ou na resposta. Em vista disso, qual seria:

**1.** a visão da comunidade (de gente, pessoas de carne e osso, como eu e você);

**2.** a recomendação em relação às regras do site.

Não me refiro a ironias, descasos ou falta de educação, mas me refiro a piadinhas pontuais mesmo, inofensivas. Mesmo inofensivas, pode um usuário interpretar como agressão ou provocação:

**Por exemplo, uma pergunta:**

> Tenho esse código:
>
> ```
> var vasco = 10;
> // vários outros códigos aqui
> ```
>
> Mas está dando erro na linha *tal*.

Então um usuário qualquer comenta: `se usasse flamengo não daria erro rsrs.`

Mesmo que o texto pressupostamente cômico não seja propriamente parte integrante  do contexto, como isso é visto nos itens **1** e **2** citados?

---

**Obs.:** é só um exemplo. Nem de futebol eu gosto.

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo? Se não for "ironias, descasos ou falta de educação", ao meu ver, é um comentário qualquer

Comment: Em geral era bem aceito e a comunidade ia bem salvo um ou outro que era mau humorado, reclamava e aí foi sendo podado, até que a comunidade ficou chata e hoje praticamente não se aceita mais, o que é só reprodução de como está a comunidade. Ainda há espaço para alguma coisa, mas tem que tomar cuidado se não ofende até o filho do vice prefeito de uma cidadezinha do Japão. Inclusive o novo código de conduta ajudará fortalecer esta tese de que a comunidade deve seguir a mais estrita seriedade porque sempre alguém pode se ofender com qualquer coisa,inclusive c/ sua pergunta,c/ meu comentário aqui.

Comment: Ninguém mais sabe definir o que é inofensivo com as "novas regras" da sociedade. Porque o que não ofendia antes hoje ofende. A intenção da pessoa não conta, a interpretação de quem ouviu é que vale. Se desculpar e dizer que não era aquilo que a pessoa quis dizer não adianta nada, a pessoa falou, foi mal interpretada, ela vira um pária, precisa ser punida e muitas vezes sua participação na sociedade comprometida, gerando um mal absurdamente maior do que o que ela teria dito causou pontualmente, se é que isto aconteceu de verdade. E tem bastante ironia no que estou dizendo.

Comment: Pelo exemplo certamente daria muita confusão, seria considerado provocação. É assim que as coisas são agora. De fato certas coisas não cabem em certos ambientes, e eu não me importaria com o colocado, é uma descontração, mas agora as pessoas se sentem mal por qualquer coisa e sempre tem gente que acha que elas precisam ser protegidas da angústia que é viver no mundo cruel.

Comment: Penso que "os incomodados que dêem flag". Acho pertinente a questão, mas penso que dá pra simplificar: Pensou em falar como ofensa? Se contenha. Falou numa boa, sem maldade? Poste e deixe por conta da moderação.

Comment: @sam eu não diria ironia, tem ataque passivo, é diferente.

Comment: O @Bacco é o rei dos comentários cômicos do SOpt, acredito que dependendo do contexto, não faça mal, mas também há de se tomar cuidado de não criar poluição visual na pergunta.

Comment: Relacionado: [Devemos aceitar piadinhas em comentários?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1931/3117)

Comment: `var palmeiras = {}; console.log(palmeiras.mundial);`

Comment: Acho que a maioria sabe diferenciar uma brincadeira divertida e descontraída de uma brincadeira racista, homofóbica, xenofóbica entre outras pejorativas. Discordando um pouco do que o @Maniero disse, não vejo o mundo/sociedade assim, quem dera se todos tivessem esse mesmo ponto de vista. Quando se brinca com algo que a pessoa **é**, está ultrapassando os limites. Um comentário como o exemplo citado acho divertido, pois, ao meu ver, você não está ridicularizando a pessoa e sim um time, ela **escolheu** torcer para ele. Essa ideia de que o que podia antes e não pode hoje não quer dizer nada(...)

Comment: (...) afinal, a sociedade muda, se transforma. Não é porque acontecia antigamente que era "permitido", muita coisa que acontecia antes não se tinha conhecimento de como afetava as outras pessoas negativamente e ninguém se importava. Hoje a tecnologia favorece para que possamos ser mais livres uns com os outros mas ao mesmo tempo nos policiar contra aquilo que prejudica as outras pessoas, simples assim. É só uma opinião.

Comment: Eu juro que ri (*com respeito*) com seus exemplos.

Comment: @bio é uma opinião e eu discordo totalmente dela - o limite quem dá é o indivíduo; preconceito acontece em nível individual; enquanto esse assunto for tratado por grupo, e enquanto as pessoas se sentirem ofendidas pelas outras, estaremos cada vez mais nos afundando na lama - existem coisas que dependem da nossa educação e do nosso bom gosto - não podemos privar a sociedade de sua liberdade por causa da má educação e mal gosto de algumas pessoas

Comment: @Blogueira não vou estender esse assunto, até porquê vai virar um debate longo. Não estamos falando de preconceito especificamente, mas sim de brincadeiras que o envolvem entre outros tipos, independente de ser nível individual ou social. Essa ideia de quem dá o limite é o indivíduo e de que preconceito acontece a nível individual eu não entendi muito bem. Se chamarmos uma pessoa de negra de modo pejorativo perto de um grupo de negros, quem vai se sentir mal, a pessoa ou o grupo social que a envolve?

Comment: Aliás, como eu disse no meu primeiro comentário (e que você disse que discordou totalmente com meu texto, mas parece que concordou parcialmente): a tecnologia favorece exatamente isso, a liberdade da sociedade. Nunca disse que é preciso privar a liberdade. Mas tudo tem limite e infelizmente não me adentro em um argumento por não ter entendido exatamente o que quis dizer com o individualismo do preconceito. Até certo ponto, sei que existe vários níveis de preconceito e não apenas o **preconceito individual**.

Comment: Só para constar, se eu não responder não me entenda mal, não quero politicar o site, embora pareça que está sendo há algum tempo.

Comment: Acho q um pouco de senso de humor torna o site mais humano, mais amigável, mas o difícil é mensurar o que é "um pouco" pra cada um, mas isso aqui também não é "fórum" onde tenha que tratar todo mundo por excelência (embora até os políticos digam *"vossa excelência é um crápula, um mal caráter"*, então....)

Comment: Se a piadinha for engraçada, pode.

Comment: @bio obrigado por concordar comigo, você mostrou que cada um tem seu critério, você tem o seu que não e o que pode, outras pessoas tem outros critérios, você tem certeza que os sues são os válido, as outras acham que são os delas. Então você acabou de comprovar o que eu disse e porque isso não funciona. E você está basicamente reproduzindo o discurso de alguns nas redes sociais, inclusive pq demonstra ñ entender os motivadores, esses argumentos são facilmente derrubados, mas isso já está bem *off-topic*, senão te mostraria que mudar o q 1 grupo determinou que não é mais permitido é irrelevante

Comment: @Maniero, Ok! Vou refletir bastante sobre tudo isso que você disse e o que eu disse também. Embora pareça estar "reproduzindo um discurso de alguns" deixo claro que essa é minha opinião e foi um texto sincero, não foi nada copiado, foi uma decisão minha. Gostaria de ver/ler você derrubando meus argumentos, mas aqui não é espaço para isso, quem sabe em outra hora.

Comment: @bio é, todo mundo acha que criou sua própria opinião, mas sempre depois que muitos estão a repetindo para todos os cantos :)

Comment: Eu até concordo que a sociedade muda. E entendo que meu papel é lutar até o fim pra voltar pro rumo, quando muda pra pior, como anda acontecendo com a qualidade do ser humano "médio" (ao menos nos países que "aparecem nos jornais", imagino que lá pro lado da Finlândia talvez esteja tudo bem ainda).

Comment: eu acho que o mundo "globalizou" rápido demais - e nossas instituições não estavam/estão preparadas para lidar com uma avalanche de pessoas jovens e desinformadas com opiniões fortes e vontade de mudar o mundo

Comment: A piadinha tem alguma coisa a ver com a pergunta ou resposta? 1) A do @VictorStafusa tem. 2) A da pergunta exemplo não tem. Um usuário tem um problema e pede ajuda. Outro, que não está mal intencionado, decide ser engraçado. A internet é muito grande, há sites para isso, aqui é lixo e deve ser sinalizado. O SOpt tem outros objetivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece-me que estás a dar demasiado pensamento à coisa.

Pelo que percebo, estamos a falar de **comentários** — como sabemos, os comentários são por natureza efémeros. Se adicionarem à discussão positivamente, a communidade e a equipa de moderação podem decidir mantê-los presentes. Se não... não se perde nada — se se perder, é porque o que lá está deveria ser editado para fazer parte da publicação.

De resto, em relação ao ofensivo ou não... temos o sistema de sinalização. É bastante simples: se me parecer que é um comentário obsoleto, sinalizo como tal e será removido. Se me parecer um comentário indelicado ou hostil, sinalizo como tal — nota que as razões de sinalização de comentários [foram alteradas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/208518) recentemente para melhor apoiar [o novo Código de Conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct). **Uma vez que o comentário é completamente superfluo, nem vale a pena entrar na discussão de "mas é indelicado para ti e para mim não..." — não adiciona nada à publicação, portanto se for sinalizado devia ser apagado.**

Comment: Só é uma pena termos que seguir um novo código de conduta que nem no nosso idioma se encontra. Eu como usuário unicamente do sopt, nunca imaginei que eu teria q saber outro idioma pra ter noção de um código de conduta do qual eu tenho que seguir.

Comment: Estou a ver agora mesmo o que preciso de fazer para este ser traduzido :) Sei que já foi traduzido para espanhol, por exemplo, portanto estou a tentar averiguar porque ainda não o temos em português ;)

Comment: "_Parece-me que estás a dar demasiado pensamento à coisa._".. desculpe-me JNat, mas eu não entendi bem essa parte. O restante entendi perfeito. Não sei se é a diferença às vezes dos portugueses.

Comment: Quero só dizer, @sam, que o problema é relativamente simples, e que pensar demasiado nele só o complica :)